# Why is twig_template_get_attributes() throwing a fatal error?

Tags: php, twig

I have twig installed via composer on a new codebase I'm working on (OSX), and on a new server I was trying install my app on. I started getting a fatal error on `twig_template_get_attributes()`

namely

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function twig_template_get_attributes() in /<path_to_here>/templates_c/a2/4e/3fbd69b54a0875d7cd3744d62bf1fa98ed4e7b1b375f904ead10b7cb27b6.php
```

I don't have this problem locally (OSX), and I was trying figure out why this is happening on my other server (Ubuntu 12.04 if that matters). When I install twig as a PHP extension the problem goes away, but my understanding is that the extension is completely optional and only optimizes one call

as per the documentation

> The C extension is optional but it brings some nice performance
>   improvements. Note that the extension is not a replacement for the PHP
>   code; it only implements a small part of the PHP code to improve the
>   performance at runtime; you must still install the regular PHP code.

and

> And from now on, Twig will automatically compile your templates to
>   take advantage of the C extension. Note that this extension does not
>   replace the PHP code but only provides an optimized version of the
>   Twig_Template::getAttribute() method.

very confused about this behavior.

Comment: Seems [twig_template_get_attributes()](https://github.com/derickr/twig-ext/blob/master/ext/twig/twig.c#L700) in also specified in the `C` ext

Comment: right, but my understanding is that this just provides and optimized version of that call.

Comment: Did you upload your cached templates to your online server by chance?

Comment: @DarkBee where would I look for that? templates_c folder? i deleted that and was still getting the error.

Comment: Then I have no clue. Because i've read templates get compiled with that particular function when the extension is enabled I thought this would solve the error.